# Traversing a Linked List in Java using "this"

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm a newbie Java programmer and need help in traversing a Java link list with "bare minimum code".

I've read previous traversal discussions and see how some folks are using a reference variables to point to the list and then use next() to traverse.

My question is - can one traverse a list without using a reference variable? In other words, could I traverse it using this.next()? The count() method below does not work (goes into infinite loop). Appreciate your help in clarifying my misconceptions. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Node {

    private Object myItem;
    private Node myNext;

    public Node(Object item, Node next) {
        myItem = item; 
        myNext = next;
    }
    public Node(Object item) {
        this(item, null);
    }

    public Object item() {
        return myItem;
    }
    public Node next() {
        return myNext;
    }

    public int count(){     
        int ctr=0;
        while (this!=null){     
            this.next();            
            ctr++;
        }
        return ctr;
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node myList = new Node("a", (new Node("b", (new Node("c",null)))));         
        System.out.println("Count: "+myList.count()); 

    }

}
```

Comment: What would you do with the intermediate result of `this.next`?

Comment: `this!=null` is just another way of saying "true". Just like, "I am not dead".

Comment: It looks like you need a better understanding of how `this` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
public int count(){
    int ctr = 1;   
    if( this.next() != null ){     
        ctr += this.next().count();  
    }
    return ctr;
}
```

This is "without using a reference variable".

Answer (score 2):

Your `this.next()` method (unlike the `next()` method in `Iterator`) doesn't change the state of the object. It just returns a value which you are not using. That's why you have an infinite loop (since `this` doesn't change, so it will never be null).

You must use the returned value :

```
public int count(){     
    int ctr=0;
    Node node = this;
    while (node!=null){     
        node = node.next();            
        ctr++;
    }
    return ctr;
}
```

Comment: I tried to traverse using - this=this.next() but it does not compile.

Comment: @DanG You can't change "this" - your statement is just like saying, "I be my neighbour."